# bash check if a variable starts with 'fatal'

Tags: bash, git

I have a variable in bash:

```sh
branchName=$(git branch --show-current)
```

There are two options for the returned value:

- banch name (e.g. master)
- `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I want to check if `branchName` starts with `fatal:`

I have tried to check if it starts with `master` and it works:

```sh
if [[ $branchName == master* ]];
    then echo "yes"
fi
echo $branchName
```

```sh
Output:
yes
master
```

but when I try to check if it starts with `fatal:` it does not work:

```sh
if [[ $branchName == fatal* ]];
    then echo "yes"
fi
```

```sh
Output:
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I try to check if it starts with fatal: it does not work:

It's because this is an error message and goes to stderr. What you capture is only the stdout.

A better approach is to check the return value instead. E.g.

```
if branchName=$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null); then
    echo "Branch is: $branchName"
else
    echo "Error: can't get branch name"
fi
```

(If command succeeds, it'd return 0; any non-zero value is usually treated as failure. The `if` statement above would be "true" when `git` return 0).

But if you do want to capture stderr, you can do:

```
branchName=$(git branch --show-current 2>&1)
```

Comment: You want `if branchName=$(git ...); then`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern